# react-datagrid programmatically pass value to the filter input box

Tags: reactjs

I have a working grid with the ability to filter. However I want to be able to programmatically pass a value to the 'search boxes' used to filter the columns. For example if there was a column called status, I want a way to pass the string 'open' to the filtering box of that column. The reason I want to do this is because when a row of the grid is pressed, it takes the user to another page, and when the user presses back I want the previous filtering of the grid to still be there (which I have stored in the redux store)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setFilterValue method:

```
public setFilterValue(col: *, val: *, triggerEvent: *)
```

http://www.reactdatagrid.com/demo/#/MultiSelectSetFilterValue?_k=ku5nh4